# Calculating the font point size after adjustsFontSizeToWidth has been performed on UIButton label

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout, uilabel

I have been using the following code to calculate a labels font size **`after the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth has been performed`** on a label that is constrained using AutoLayout and it works nicely:

```
NSStringDrawingContext *labelContext = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
labelContext.minimumScaleFactor = label.minimumScaleFactor;
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : label.font}];    
[attributedString boundingRectWithSize:label.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:labelContext];
_fontSize = label.font.pointSize * labelContext.actualScaleFactor;
```

In my storyboard I have set the lines to 1 and a minimum font scale as follows:

[image]
[image]

However I have tried using the exact same method on a `UIButton` the only difference being that I access the titleLabel property of the `UIButton` like this:

```
NSStringDrawingContext *labelContext = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
labelContext.minimumScaleFactor = _Button.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor;
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_Button.titleLabel.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : _Button.titleLabel.font}];

[attributedString boundingRectWithSize:_Button.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:labelContext];


_fontSize = _Button.titleLabel.font.pointSize * labelContext.actualScaleFactor;
```

And while the label.font of my button is adjusting the font size according to the width, the calculation of the font size does not return a smaller font size than that which is set in the Storyboard.

It may be because I have not explicity set a minimum scale factor for the Button.label in the story board as I have done with the UILabel.  I have tried setting the `minimumScaleFactor` on the button.titleLabel in the `viewDidLoad` method, but this results in the fontSize result being scaled exactly by that figure, and doesn't seem to take into consideration the width of the bounding button box.

Answer (score 0):

Using `titleLabel` to get the title text, font color or shadow color is not a good idea. Have you tried `-attributedTitleForState:`?

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [_Button attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

To clarify, my suggestion was to replace how you set `attributedString`.

From the question, replace

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_Button.titleLabel.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : _Button.titleLabel.font}];
```

with

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [_Button attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

None of that matters, if `-attributedTitleForState:` returns `nil`.

Maybe try replacing

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_Button.titleLabel.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : _Button.titleLabel.font}];
```

with

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[_Button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : _Button.titleLabel.font}];
```

Comment: This returns a nil object unfortunately.

Comment: I'm trying to access the newly calculated font point size not any of the above

Comment: @LindaKeating If `-attributedTitleForState:` returned `nil`, then the button doesn't have a title ["If no attributed title has been set for UIControlStateNormal, returns nil."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/attributedTitleForState:)

Comment: I think more specifically it doesn't have an attributedTitle - but it does have a title. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleForState:

Comment: @LindaKeating For other controls, like UILabel, you can set the text value and get back the attributed text value. Now that I think of it, I think UIButton works differently, so this assumption is false. Either way, you should not use `titleLabel.text`, try using `-titleForState:` instead.